# How to extract analytics information like Google Analytics?

Tags: http, google-analytics, analytics

I'm building my own URL shortener service for myself. I'd like to add an admin page which displays some basic analytics information like how Google Analytics displays page views, unique visitors, geographical region, social media referral, etc. I know Google Analytics works by using cookies and pushing each page view to their servers, but I don't think I need to do that in order to get some good information.

**What type of analytics information can I extract from a basic HTTP request?**

I'm using Ruby, but the answer will probably be applicable to multiple languages.

Comment: What kinds of analytics information are you looking to display? Where is the data coming from? Is it coming from Google Analytics?

Comment: Let's say I post my short link on various social media sites. I want to know which social media site they came from, where in the world they are geographically, if they have clicked the link more than once (total uniques), etc.

Comment: But more importantly, I want to know what I can extract. What are all the types of analytics that are extractable by doing it yourself instead of using an analytics provider? Or must you use something like google analytics and use some sort of API to display this information?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Google Analytics, you can use the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol) to send data directly to the GA back-end from any environment where you can make an HTTP request (e.g. server or client).

When an end user makes a request to one of your short links, you can extract information like the user agent string (if it's from a browser) and the IP address (which gives you geographic location information) and if there are cookies present, you can set the [clientId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) or [userId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid) to track unique visits. If you send that info to GA it will automatically process it for you (like, you don't need to determine geo yourself) and allow you to run all the usual reports. (Some things won't apply, like time on site or pages per session, but that should be obvious.)

In terms of building an admin dashboard, you can use the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed) to do all your reporting. The Embed API handles auth for you and has a pretty easy-to-use API for displaying GA data.

If you **aren't** using Google Analytics, you can do all the same stuff; you'd just have to process all that data yourself, i.e. parse the user agent string, translate the IP address to geo data, etc.